What's the mathematical relationship between Characters, Syllables, Morphemes, Words?
Why was What's the mathematical relationship between Characters, Syllables, Morphemes, Words? closed as duplicate of Character vs. glyph vs. grapheme/morphogram vs. ideogram vs. logogram vs. pictogram vs. symbol vs. syllable? Isn't it obvious they differ?
The first asks about the quantitative relations between four terms. The second asks about the semantic differences between eight terms.

I'm didn't participate in closing the question, but (at first glance) it looks like the first question is answered by the answer in the second question.  In any case, would it be possible to edit the closed question to highlight the distinction?

Of course the questions differ, but if you didn't manage to capture your query from the first question inside the query from your second, then your question was ill-posed. An analogous set of questions wouldn't even fly on Mathematics or Physics SE - would you seriously ask (1) What is f(x) - g(x) then (2) Is f(x) > g(x) in separate questions?

Your proposed inequality in the second question

number of words ≤ morphemes ≤ characters ≤ syllables

is essentially a paraphrase of Table 3.5 in Rogers (2004):

which appeared in both of your questions. Your second question is equivalent to asking, why is Table 3.5 arranged like so, to which I have provided my answer here:

Overwhelming monosyllabicity of Chinese characters (point 1) → number of characters = syllables
Nonsplittability of some bisyllabic/bi-character Chinese words (point 2) → number of words / morphemes ≤ characters
Splittability of most Chinese words (point 2) → number of words ≤ morphemes

So in a way, your second question is already answered. Of course, you can rephrase your second question by asking if there are any counter-examples that disprove the implied inequality from the Table. E.g., in the case of Japanese, it is possible due to the ateji phenomenon that the number of characters > syllables:

(Japanese)        香具師
(Hiragana)        やし
(Transliteration) yashi
(Translation)     street performer

and in Chinese there are some ligatures (合字) that are polysyllabic, which support the smaller-than sign in "number of characters ≤ syllables" rule. For example, the following is the ligature of 招財進寶 and is indeed read as zhāocái jìnbǎo, meaning 'let riches and treasures come into the house'. These are however rare, so I think my answer already suffices.


Thanks. "number of words ≤ morphemes ≤ characters ≤ syllables" But this was just my guess. I didn't know if correct or not. That question should be reopened, so that it can be answered by your answer here.

@user52144 As one of the close voters, I am still not convinced enough that your educated guess is a stand-alone question. It is a "tautological" derivation of my answer in the original post. Any doubts arising thereof can be efficiently dealt with by your commenting under my original answer. Of course, other users with sufficient reputation can still vote to reopen the question.
